# DataTables imprimer dos veces encabezado y pie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable

Estoy utilizando la gema jquery-datatables-rails, mi problema es que el encabezado se imprime dos veces y se queda así cuando regreso a esta página.

[image: DataTable duplica encabezado]

El script que estoy utilizando al finalizar la vista para iniciar el dataTable al finalizar la vista

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#orders').dataTable({
      "language": {
            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    "Primero",
                "sLast":     "Último",
                "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        }

    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente forma

```
<table id="myTable" data-turbolinks="false">
 ...
</table>
```

La solución la encontré aquí https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36875/duplicate-wrapper-with-browser-forward-back-button